# Traefik can't connect to server with docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, traefik

I'm trying to install `gitea` and `traefik` in an Alibaba Cloud instance but I can't get any page or response from `traefik`. How can I debug this? `docker logs traefik` has no errors

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"

networks:
  gitea_net:
    external: true
  internal:
    external: false

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=gitea
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=gitea
      - POSTGRES_DB=gitea
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=false"
    networks:
      - internal
    volumes:
      - ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    command: --docker
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.backend=dashboard"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik.mydomain.com"
      - "traefik.port=8080"
    networks:
      - gitea_net
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - ./acme.json:/acme.json
    container_name: traefik
    restart: always

  server:
    image: gitea/gitea:latest
    environment:
      - USER_UID=1000
      - USER_GID=1000
    restart: always
    networks:
      - internal
    volumes:
      - ./gitea:/data
    ports:
      - "3000"
      - "22"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enabled=true"
      - "traefik.backend=gitea"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:gitea.mydomain.com"
      - "traefik.docker.network=gitea_net"
      - "traefik.port=3000"
    networks:
      - internal
      - gitea_net
    depends_on:
      - db
      - traefik
```

Here is my `traefik.toml`

```
#Traefik Global Configuration
debug = true
checkNewVersion = true
logLevel = "ERROR"

#Define the EntryPoint for HTTP and HTTPS
defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]

#Define the HTTP port 80 and
#HTTPS port 443 EntryPoint
#Enable automatically redirect HTTP to HTTPS
[entryPoints]
[entryPoints.http]
address = ":80"
[entryPoints.http.redirect]
entryPoint = "https"
[entryPoints.https]
address = ":443"
[entryPoints.https.tls]

#Enable Traefik Dashboard on port 8080
#with basic authentication method

[entryPoints.dash]
address=":8080"
[entryPoints.dash.auth]
[entryPoints.dash.auth.basic]
    users = [
        "admin:$apr1$nw$PAVvqQK30eAdrY0l9KCnK1",
    ]

[api]
entrypoint="dash"
dashboard = true

#Enable retry sending a request if the network error
[retry]

#Define Docker Backend Configuration
[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "mydomain.com"
watch = true
exposedbydefault = false

#Letsencrypt Registration
#Define the Letsencrypt ACME HTTP challenge
[acme]
email = "mark@gmail.com"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
OnHostRule = true
  [acme.httpChallenge]
  entryPoint = "http"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be wrong but your setup may be only valid for Traefik before `2.0`.

You can check it quickly by changing the docker image tag from `traefik:latest` to `traefik:1.7`.

If you are still not able to make it work, then please try my setup that I know is working, because is being used. If my setup works for you then you can compare it with yours and see how you make yours to work. The main difference from mine to yours is that I use Treafik 1.7 and that I deploy Traefik as a separated docker stack in the server, because I believe this is the proper way of doing, at least if you want to take advange of using it to tun as many services as you can in the same server.

Another thing to watch out for is that the `acme.json` file to store the Letsencrypt certificates must have `600` permissions. But if I recall well this permissions issues will not cause traefik to keep restarting, but not sure, and I have not detailed  in my [bash script](https://github.com/approov/shipfast-api-protection/blob/b45b4ced2a77a4c140fa29bc09b941b8a6c534c6/bin/setup-online-server.sh#L49-L51) to setup Traefik:

```sh
# Traefik will not create the certificates if we don't fix the permissions
#  for the file where it stores the LetsEncrypt certificates.
chmod 600 acme.json
```

[docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/approov/shipfast-api-protection/tree/28b6ce460b87ab660e81c4f5faeddd3d00728aaa/traefik):

```
version: '2.3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:1.7
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - traefik
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - ./acme.json:/acme.json
    container_name: traefik
    labels:
      - "traefik.acme.email=${TRAEFIK_ACME_EMAIL:? Missing TRAEFIK_ACME_EMAIL env var.}"
      - "traefik.docker.domain=${TRAEFIK_DOCKER_DOMAIN:? Missing TRAEFIK_DOCKER_DOMAIN env var.}"
networks:
  traefik:
    external: true
```

The network is external, therefore you need to run `docker network create traefik`.

The variables in the `docker-compose.yml` file come from a `.env` [file](https://github.com/approov/shipfast-api-protection/blob/28b6ce460b87ab660e81c4f5faeddd3d00728aaa/traefik/.env.example):

```
TRAEFIK_DOCKER_DOMAIN=dev.example.com
TRAEFIK_ACME_EMAIL=YOUR@EMAIL.COM
```

[traefik.toml](https://github.com/approov/shipfast-api-protection/blob/28b6ce460b87ab660e81c4f5faeddd3d00728aaa/traefik/traefik.toml):

```
debug = false

logLevel = "ERROR"
defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]

[web]
address = ":8080"

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"

  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]

[retry]

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
watch = true
exposedByDefault = false

[acme]
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true
[acme.httpChallenge]
entryPoint = "http"
```

An example of attaching a docker compose service from another `docker-compose.yml` file can be found [here](https://github.com/approov/shipfast-api-protection/blob/28b6ce460b87ab660e81c4f5faeddd3d00728aaa/docker-compose.yml#L49-L57):

```
  service-name:
    ....
    networks:
      - shipfast
      - traefik
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.backend=${ENVIRONMENT:-dev}.shipfast-api"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik"
      - "traefik.port=${SHIPFAST_HTTP_PORT}"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${SHIPFAST_PUBLIC_DOMAIN:-localhost}"

.....

networks:
  shipfast:
    driver: "bridge"
  traefik:
    external: true
```